# How to write unit test cases (XCTest) in UIWebView / WebKit - Swift

Tags: xcode, swift4, ios12, xctestcase

I want to write unit test cases (XCTest) in UIWebView/ Webkit- Swift
Please post any helpful link, example, or tutorial.

Thank you.
Shriram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way is to create fake navigation actions to call manually the delegate.

In this question you have a good example to write test cases of this way. [unit-testing-wknavigationdelegate-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277915/unit-testing-wknavigationdelegate-functions)

Example to test loading in navigation:

```
// setup
let fakeNavigation = WKNavigation()

delegateObject.refresh() // Set loading to true and init the web view
XCTAssertTrue(delegateObject.loading)

delegateObject.webView(webView, didFinish: fakeNavigation)
XCTAssertFalse(delegateObject.loading)
```

Example to test the policy:

```
class FakeNavigationAction: WKNavigationAction {
    let testRequest: URLRequest
    override var request: URLRequest {
        return testRequest
    }

    init(testRequest: URLRequest) {
        self.testRequest = testRequest
        super.init()
    }
}
```

```
// setup
var receivedPolicy: WKNavigationActionPolicy?
let fakeAction = FakeNavigationAction(testRequest: ...)

// act
delegateObject.webView(webView, decidePolicyFor: fakeAction, decisionHandler: { 
    receivedPolicy = $0 
})


XCTAssertEqual(receivedPolicy, theExpectedValue)
```

Comment: Please share example