# Unit testing WKNavigationDelegate functions swift

Tags: swift, webkit, wkwebview, wknavigationdelegate

I have a `UIViewController` that implements some `WKNavigationDelegate` functions, and I want to unit test the logic in these functions. Here's an example:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
             decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
             decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        return
    }

    if url.absoluteString != "https://my-approved-url" {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        return
    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

I'd like my unit test to make sure `decisionHandler` is called with the right `WKNavigationActionPolicy` based on the `request.url` of the `WKNavigationAction`.

I can't figure out how to test this function, however. Calling `.load()` on the webview does not trigger the delegate functions when I'm running my test project. I have also tried to call this function directly to test it, but it doesn't seem to be possible to instantiate a new `WKNavigationAction` of my own (.request is read-only).

What is the right way to unit test logic in `WKNavigationDelegate` functions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit testing WKNavigationDelegate functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277915/unit-testing-wknavigationdelegate-functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second approach of directly calling the delegate method is the better approach as you are not relying on any behavior of WebKit in your unit tests.

The problem of not being able to instantiate a WKNavigationAction can be solved by subclassing. Create a `MockNavigationAction` which returns the desired request you need for testing like so:

```
final class MockNavigationAction: WKNavigationAction {
    var mockedRequest: URLRequest!
    override var request: URLRequest {
        return mockedRequest
    }
```

And then in your unit test call the delegate method directly:

```
func test_AllowsCorrectURL() {
    let sut = ViewController()
    let action = MockNavigationAction()
    action.mockedRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://my-approved-url")!)
    let allowExpectation = expectation(description: "Allows action")
    sut.webView(WKWebView(), decidePolicyFor: action) { policy in
        XCTAssertEqual(policy, .allow)
        allowExpectation.fulfill()
    }
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 1.0)
}
```

Comment: When i use sut.webView(WKWebView(), decidePolicyFor: action) { policy in
        XCTAssertEqual(policy, .allow)
        allowExpectation.fulfill()
    } getting 'Cannot call value of non-function type 'WKWebView?'' error. in swift version 5. Any idea why?