# Releasing WKNavigationAction subclass crashes on iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, ios15

For unit testing I have subclassed `WKNavigationAction`. It's a common practice and can be found across the internet and in big SDKs, too.

On iOS 15 releasing an instance of it leads to a crash inside WebKit.

Stacktrace:

```
Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x0000000130d8b702 in WTF::RunLoop::dispatch(WTF::Function<void ()>&&) ()
#1  0x0000000134ed41e4 in WebCoreObjCScheduleDeallocateOnMainRunLoop(objc_class*, objc_object*) ()
#2  0x000000011290711d in -[WKNavigationAction dealloc] ()
#3  0x000000010cf2f9f7 in objc_object::sidetable_release(bool, bool) ()
```

Example Playground:

```swift
import WebKit

class MockNavigationAction: WKNavigationAction {}

var navigationAction: WKNavigationAction? = MockNavigationAction()

navigationAction = nil
```

Suggestions about how to solve this are very appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a WebKit bug, you need to kickstart the framework, otherwise the deallocation fails.

Just create a dummy webview sometimes during the app/tests startup:

```swift
_ = WKWebView()
```

This workaround will fix the crash, as creating a `WKWebView` will launch the WebKit engine, and will likely initialize the values that were causing the crash.

Theoretically, you should not need the above code, as you'll anyway have to pass a `WKWebView` instance to the delegate methods.

Comment: Meh, that's ugly. But works indeed.

Comment: @mbi, yeah it's not beautiful code,  however theoretically, you should not need it, as you'll anyway have to pass a `WKWebView` instance for the delegate methods.

Comment: unit testing isolated code here that works straight with `WKNavigationAction`